# Search functionality in Github/Repo/Projects

Tags: search, github, projects

Update: The issue was forwarded by Github’s Support to their Engineers (13.02.2018).

I am currently learning Github and want to integrate the Projects tab in my repository into my workflow.
I did the small tutorial and am now trying to make columns with my costum tags, ie: TODO, DONE, IDEA, etc.

1. I figured that I can add labels in the Issues tab
   [Projects tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ap3R.png) and search for them. That's already a great plus.
2. The picture in 1. includes some cards but using search results in some unexpected behaviour
   2.1 Search: "feature", returns the result in the first column `TODO`, but won't return the third column `FEATURE` [Search Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1rC1.png)
   2.2 Search: "more", won't return the third column `FEATURE` aswell.
   [Search result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PTZv.png)

I looked into [Tracking the progress of your work with project boards](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-notes-to-a-project-board/) already but couldn't find an answer there.

The questions/issues are:
- Why did the searching for "more" not result into anything?
- What do I have to type into the search bar to get the result for "more"?

I tried `is:note more` but it seems `is:note` will just returns the notes in the columns and accepts no other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support replied and issue is now fixed.